# Dynamic SQL - Removing a Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Have a question and was hoping someone can help me with. The dynamic sql set in @sqlMain, is currently grabbing a column called *lg.ColorGroup*, however I actually do not want to grab that column, when I remove it though I can't do an *ORDER BY ColorGroup*. Is there a way to make the result set returned ordered by ColorGroup without it selected. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO     #ServerList
SELECT DISTINCT ServerURL, ServerName, InstanceType
FROM            [CR_PIT_01].[dbo].[EFDM_Servers]
WHERE           InstanceType = 'Production'

SELECT          @ProgramList = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ServerName) FROM #ServerList ORDER BY ServerURL FOR XML PATH (''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
PRINT           @ProgramList

CREATE Table    #ServerListGrouped
(
    Name varchar(300),
    ColorGroup int
)

INSERT INTO     #ServerListGrouped
SELECT DISTINCT Name, (case when SUBSTRING(LOWER(Name), 0, 3) = 'y_' then 2 when SUBSTRING(Lower(Name), 0, 3) = 'z_' then 3 when Exists (Select BuiltInField FROM [CR_PIT_01].[dbo].[EFDM_BuiltInFields] WHERE BuiltInField = Name) then 4 else 1 end) As FieldUsage
FROM            CR_PIT_01.dbo.EFDM_ProjectFields
ORDER BY        FieldUsage ASC, Name

SET             @sqlMain = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT P.Name, lg.ColorGroup, P.'+ @FilterValue +' , S.ServerName FROM [CR_PIT_01].[dbo].[EFDM_ProjectFields] AS P JOIN #ServerList AS S ON S.ServerURL = P.ServerURL Join #ServerListGrouped LG on p.Name = lg.Name) AS P PIVOT ( MIN(' + @FilterValue + ') FOR ServerName IN (' + @ProgramList + ')) AS PIV  Where Name LIKE (''%' + @Name + '%'') ORDER BY colorgroup, PIV.Name'
--SET               @sqlMain = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT P.Name,  P.'+ @FilterValue +' , S.ServerName FROM [CR_PIT_01].[dbo].[EFDM_ProjectFields] AS P JOIN #ServerList AS S ON S.ServerURL = P.ServerURL ) AS P PIVOT ( MIN(' + @FilterValue + ') FOR ServerName IN (' + @ProgramList + ')) AS PIV  Where Name LIKE (''%' + @Name + '%'') ORDER BY PIV.Name;'
PRINT           @sqlMain;
--EXEC          sp_executesql @sqlMain;


DROP TABLE      #ServerList
DROP TABLE      #ServerListGrouped
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure that the `ORDER BY` in your `INSERT...SELECT` actually does anything useful. You aren't necessarily guaranteed to get them back in the same order, and it just looks like you're `JOIN`ing to that temp table anyway. Order doesn't have meaning, so this step can be eliminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the asterisk in your dynamic sql in the first select clause to an explicit list that doesn't include colorgroup.

```
SET             @sqlMain = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT P.Name, lg.ColorGroup, P.'+ @FilterValue +' , S.ServerName FROM
```

becomes

```
SET             @sqlMain = 'SELECT Name, '+ @FilterValue +' , ServerName FROM (SELECT P.Name, lg.ColorGroup, P.'+ @FilterValue +' , S.ServerName FROM ...
```

Comment: thank you you r answer helped me arrive at the answer. I removed the colorgroup as you specified and inserted Name and '@ProgramList' (which I believed you meant) and it worked for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Remove ColorGroup from the outer SELECT list, and leave it in the ORDER BY.

A column doesn't have to be selected to be used for ordering.

It just means you have to specify the outer select list, instead of using `SELECT *`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT PIV.Name FROM (...) ORDER BY colorgroup, PIV.Name` is a valid SQL.